# Where to find logs from Postgres 11.1 on FreeBSD 11.2?

Tags: logging, postgresql, freebsd, syslog

Having built Postgres 11.1 on my FreeBSD 11.2 machine, where might I find the logs output from Postgres.

Specifically, when attempting to start Postgres for the first time, I get an error message from `pg_ctl` telling me to examine the logs for an explanation of the problem.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/db/postgres/data11 -l logfile start
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

When building Postgres, the final output mentions:

```
NB. FreeBSD's PostgreSQL port logs to syslog by default
  See ~pgsql/data/postgresql.conf for more info
```

When I look in that file, the only entry on logging is:

> log_destination = 'syslog'

➥ How do I query syslog for my Postgres logs?

Comment: Have you initialized your database with command `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/postgresql initdb`?  Please prepare a log file and show us any errors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will have to create a dedicated log file for PostgreSQL:

```
touch /var/log/postgresql.log
chown postgres:wheel /var/log/postgresql.log
chmod 640 /var/log/postgresql.log
```

After that update `/etc/syslog.conf` and redirect messages from PostgreSQL to the log file just created by adding entry like this:

```
local0.*     /var/log/postgresql.log
```

Don't forget to restart syslogd to apply your changes:

```
kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslog.pid`
```

Answer (score 0):

@taro's answer is the right approach, but unfortunately adding a filter for `local0.*   /var/log/postgresql.log` will redirect all syslog local0-directed messages to `/var/log/postgresql.log`, including output from other applications and daemons.

The correct answer would be to either add a specific app filter to `/etc/syslog.conf` or create a postgres-specific syslog directive file in `/etc/syslog.d/postgres.conf` or `/usr/local/etc/syslog.d/postgres.conf` (you may need to create the `/usr/local/etc/syslog.d` directory first).

If going with the first approach, you would add the following line to `/etc/syslog.conf`:

```
postgres.*  /var/log/postgresql.log
```

If going with the second approach (recommended), you would create a new file `postgres.conf` in one of the `syslog.d` directories with the following contents:

```
!postgres
*.*     /var/log/postgresql.log
```